# How to close/stop custom screensaver in windows

Tags: c#, windows, screensaver

I made a simple c# app to use as a screensaver. I renamed the exe to scr, right-click, install, and set the start time like a usual screensaver. I also added a button on the app to close it.

My question is, how can I get my c# app to terminate like a normal screensaver would - on mouse move, computer that goes to sleep etc. I know I can add the mouse_move event to the form or some control and then close the app BUT this prevents windows-sleep to close the screensaver/app and go to sleep!

Any ideas?

I think my problem might be that the computer doesn't see itself as Idle when the custom screensaver shows?

Comment: *this prevents windows-sleep to close the screensaver/app and go to sleep!* What? if you have a custom screensaver why would you want the computer to sleep?

Comment: Look at the screensaver api. Will help you a lot : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144066(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Alfie, I'm using my computer also as a media center so I have the TV connected to it. The TV turns of after some time if it has no input. When the computer goes to sleep, there is no input so the TV will turn of - which is what I want :)

Comment: Thank you Turrican, I'll have a look :D